# Commutative matrices and symmetric property

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume we have two commutating matrices, [A,B]=0. Can we say that A and B are symmetric?

Regards

Comment: No, $[A, A^n] = 0$ for any $A$ and $n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, we cannot say in general that $0=[A,B]=AB-BA$ implies that $A$ or $B$ are symmetric: take $A$ non-symmetric and $B$ the identity matrix, for example. 
However a related statement is true: if $A$ and $B$ are symmetric, then $AB$ is not symmetric unless $A$ and $B$ commute.
Indeed, $(AB)^T=AB$ if and only if $AB=BA$ for symmetric matrices $A,B$, i.e., $[A,B]=0$.